# Match values based on group value with columns values and merge it in two columns

Tags: python, pandas

df

```
index    group1    group2     a      b     c      d  
-
0        a         b          1      2     NaN    NaN
1        b         c          NaN    5     1      NaN
2        c         d          NaN    NaN   6      9
4        b         a          1      7     NaN    NaN
5        d         a          6      NaN   NaN    5
```

df expect

```
index    group1    group2     one    two 
-
0        a         b          1      2    
1        b         c          5      1
2        c         d          6      9
4        b         a          7      1
5        d         a          5      6
```

I want to match values based on columns ['group1','group2'] and append to columns [‘one','two'] by order. For example, row index 5: group1 is 'd', so it will take value of 5 from 'd' first, and then it will do group2.

I am trying to use lookup function: `df.one = df.lookup(df.index, df.group1)`, it works on small data, but not with big data with lots of columns, and values get mixed up.

Comment: Not sure what means `values mixed up`, so not possible use `df['one'] = df.lookup(df.index, df.group1)
df['two'] = df.lookup(df.index, df.group2)` ?

Comment: Can yu explain more?

Comment: Yes I did that, but it doesn't work for me on the real dataset with more columns. It doesn't match.

Comment: Maybe there is another way to do this instead of lookup?

Comment: lookup is really fast, if not matched I guess problem in data - some traling whitespace maybe or not existing columns. So is possible create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) also with problematic data, explain more why your solution cannot be used?

Comment: @Juninhoy, looks like you are working on test practice, can you share the dataset you are working/

Comment: Basically soccer matches (group1 and group2 are 'home' and 'away') https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/soccer-api/club/spi_matches.csv

Comment: I can send you the ones that I already did the columns with each teams.

Comment: I'm trying to get score of each team regardless of if they are home or away.

Comment: You can create a list of `df.columns` and then use `groupby` and a `lambda` but this is insanely slow compared to `lookup`: `df.groupby(["index", "group1"]).apply(lambda x: x[columns[columns.index(x.name[1])]]).values`.

Comment: @user3471881 `df.groupby([df.index, 'group1']).apply(lambda x: x[x.name[1]]).values` This is what I wanted!!! And it's as fast as lookup on my end. Thank you!!!!!!